# Keep only parent directories inside a listbox Or a list(Of String)

Tags: vb.net, linq, list, listbox

I have a Listbox that contains a list of Directories Paths. I want to **remove** each subfolders (**existing in the list**) and **keep** only their parents (**also existing in the list**).

**Original List:**

```
D:\Folder_1
D:\Folder_1\Folder_98
D:\Folder_2\Folder_8
D:\Folder_2\Folder_8\Folder_12
D:\Folder_2\Folder_8\Folder_1\Folder_112\
D:\Folder_3\Folder_5
D:\Folder_3\Folder_9
D:\Folder_3\Folder_1
E:\Folder_4\Folder_0
E:\Folder_4\Folder_77
E:\Folder_4\Folder_1
E:\
E:\Folder_4\Folder_01\Folder_0
F:\
H:\
```

**Final List:**

```
D:\Folder_1
D:\Folder_2\Folder_8
D:\Folder_3\Folder_5
D:\Folder_3\Folder_9
D:\Folder_3\Folder_1
E:\
F:\
H:\
```

For example I tried:

```
Folders_List_In_Listbox = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String)().ToList()

    For Each Fold In Folders_List_In_Listbox
        Select Case True
            Case Path.GetFullPath(Fold).StartsWith(Path.GetFullPath(Mon_Repertoire))
                Folders_List_In_Listbox.Remove(Fold)
            Case Path.GetFullPath(Mon_Repertoire).StartsWith(Path.GetFullPath(Fold))
                Folders_List_In_Listbox_To_Remove.Add(Repertoire)
        End Select
    Next

ListBox1.DataSource = Folders_List_In_Listbox
```

How can we do that if our Directories are listed in a listbox Or inside a list(Of String)?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. I really don't see how you get from the original list to the final one.

Comment: I agree with itsme86, I see no logic in what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @itsme86 I have updated my question.

Comment: @VisualVincent I don't see any thing illogic in my example. If I Have  "D:\Folder_1"   And   "D:\Folder_1\Folder_98\Folder3"   in my list, I would like to keep the 1st folder and delete the 2nd from my list.

Comment: One of the non-logical things is for example that you completely remove `Folder_4`. Another is that you remove `D:\Folder_1\Folder_98` but you keep `D:\Folder_2\Folder_8`. Performing this automatically is hard, maybe even close to impossible. -- **EDIT:** A third non-logical thing I just saw is that you also remove the entire `D:\Folder_2\Folder_8\Folder_1\Folder_112\ `.

Comment: @VisualVincent (1)- Sorry, I have a mistake, "D:\Folder_2\Folder_8" should be deleted. (Fixed in the example)  (2)- "D:\Folder_2\Folder_8\Folder_1\Folder_112\" has "D:\Folder_2\Folder_8" as parent. (3)- I removed All "Folder_4" because thier parent exists "E:\"

Comment: Oh, I see. Well then, I should have some code for this shortly.

Answer (score 0):

**I created a code to solve my problem:**

```
Dim List1 As List(Of String) = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String)().ToList()
Dim List2 As List(Of String) = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String)().ToList(

For Each Mon_Repertoire In List1
    If List2.Any(Function(X) Path.GetFullPath(Mon_Repertoire).StartsWith(Path.GetFullPath(X)) _
                 And Path.GetFullPath(X).Length <> Path.GetFullPath(Mon_Repertoire).Length) Then
        List2.Remove(Mon_Repertoire)
    End If
Next

ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
ListBox1.DataSource = List2
```

Comment: Ah. Sorry for not getting back earlier, something came up. This was similar to what I would've done however I would've sorted the list and manually iterated every item.

Comment: Two little improvement tips: **1)** You should use `AndAlso` instead of `And` since `AndAlso` is short-circuited, thus will not evaluate the right side if the left size evaluates to `False`. **2)** You should probably call `ToLower()` on the strings you are comparing. This is because local file system paths are case-insensitive and using your current code `D:\Folder_1` will not be the same as `D:\FOLDER_1`.

Comment: Here's how you could take case-insensitivity into account: `Path.GetFullPath(Mon_Repertoire).ToLower().StartsWith(Path.GetFullPath(X).ToLower())`.

Comment: @VisualVincent Thanks for your tips. I will improve my code. But I don't understand why sorting list.

Comment: @VisualVincent I will be happy that you show me your code if you can. Otherwise thank you anyway.

Comment: I would've sorted the list, shortest path to longest, then ran `StartsWith()` on every item with every item. Nothing special really, pretty much the same technique you used.

Comment: @VisualVincent I did that in my own code, but i didn't post it here. I used this line:  List1 = List1.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Length).ToList()